# SVG for background

Tags: css, svg

I tried to use a svg for a background and it works in local but not when I upload it to an ftp.

It has a png fallback for IE and others that not support svg. But in all cases I just see the png.

(Just for the example use a red square for the svg and a very different think a logo of skype.png  for the fall back):
http://jsfiddle.net/snG8w/
http://codepen.io/pen/9135/2

How to put a svg in in this background?

HTML:

```
<div id="quadrat"></div>​
```

CSS:

```
#quadrat {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  line-height:200px;
  background-image:  url('http://mig-marketing.com/proves/retina/skype.png');
  background-image:  none,url('http://mig-marketing.com/proves/retina/rectangle.svg'), url('http://mig-marketing.com/proves/retina/skype.png');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}​
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing the URLs with relative URLs? I imagine the browser might restrict full URLs.

Comment: does the 'none' trump the others?

Comment: @DA, No. It works perfectly well if you have a properly served svg: http://jsfiddle.net/WTkbA/

Comment: Unclenorton: your svg works well, but I don't understand why. I did a very simple svg with Illustrator. It can be seen well in the browser: http://mig-marketing.com/proves/retina/rectangle.svg The problem is when I put it in a background. Why your svg works well allways? I don't see the difference?

Comment: Clafou: I tried relative URL and nothing changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are serving the [svg image](http://mig-marketing.com/proves/retina/rectangle.svg) with a 'text/xml' mediatype. While that's technically fine, it's quite possible that browsers disallow that in scenarios like this one, where only images are allowed. Try configuring your server to send the official svg mediatype 'image/svg+xml' instead, that should work.

Some more details for how to configure your webserver can be found e.g [here](http://planetsvg.com/tools/mime.php?url=http://mig-marketing.com/proves/retina/rectangle.svg).

**Update:** added link to the svg image that gets served with 'text/xml'.

Comment: In the Fiddle I cannot see the svg. You see just the png.: http://jsfiddle.net/snG8w/ In codepen (similar to Fiddle) the same: http://codepen.io/pen/9135/2 I suppose this means that the problem is not the server?

Comment: You are right, the problem was in the server where the svg is hosted. Thank you so much!